# Saving data back into Cassandra as RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to read messages from Kafka, process the data, and then add the data into cassandra as if it is an RDD.

My trouble is saving the data back into cassandra.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

appName = 'Kafka_Cassandra_Test'
kafkaBrokers = '1.2.3.4:9092'
topic = 'test'
cassandraHosts = '1,2,3'
sparkMaster = 'spark://mysparkmaster:7077'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf()
    conf.set('spark.cassandra.connection.host', cassandraHosts)

    sc = SparkContext(sparkMaster, appName, conf=conf)

    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": kafkaBrokers})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
        .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.saveToCassandra('coreglead_v2', 'wordcount')

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

And the error:

```
[root@gasweb2 ~]# spark-submit --jars /var/spark/lib/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.5.0-RC1-s_2.11 /var/spark/scripts/kafka_cassandra.py
Ivy Default Cache set to: /root/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /root/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/var/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
datastax#spark-cassandra-connector added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;1.5.0-RC1-s_2.11 in spark-packages
    found org.apache.cassandra#cassandra-clientutil;2.2.2 in central
    found com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0-rc1 in central
    found io.netty#netty-handler;4.0.33.Final in central
    found io.netty#netty-buffer;4.0.33.Final in central
    found io.netty#netty-common;4.0.33.Final in central
    found io.netty#netty-transport;4.0.33.Final in central
    found io.netty#netty-codec;4.0.33.Final in central
    found io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-core;3.1.2 in central
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 in central
    found org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.3.2 in central
    found com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 in central
    found org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 in central
    found joda-time#joda-time;2.3 in central
    found com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0 in central
    found org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.7 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 647ms :: artifacts dl 15ms
    :: modules in use:
    com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0-rc1 from central in [default]
    com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 from central in [default]
    com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0 from central in [default]
    datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;1.5.0-RC1-s_2.11 from spark-packages in [default]
    io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-core;3.1.2 from central in [default]
    io.netty#netty-buffer;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
    io.netty#netty-codec;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
    io.netty#netty-common;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
    io.netty#netty-handler;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
    io.netty#netty-transport;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
    joda-time#joda-time;2.3 from central in [default]
    org.apache.cassandra#cassandra-clientutil;2.2.2 from central in [default]
    org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.3.2 from central in [default]
    org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 from central in [default]
    org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.7 from central in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   16  |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   16  |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 16 already retrieved (0kB/14ms)
16/02/15 16:26:14 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/spark/scripts/kafka_cassandra.py", line 27, in <module>
    counts.saveToCassandra('coreglead_v2', 'wordcount')
AttributeError: 'TransformedDStream' object has no attribute 'saveToCassandra'
```

---

From searching around I have found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra/issues/25), however this seems to be related to a different library (I can't use this library as I am using Cassandra 3.0 and it is not supported yet).

The goal is to create aggregated data from a single message (the wordcount is just for testing) and insert it into several tables.

I am close to just using the [Datastax Python Driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver) and writing the statements myself, but is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the Spark Cassandra Connector by Datastax which doesn't have support for python at the RDD / DStream level. Only Dataframes are supported. See the [docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md) for more information.

I've authored a wrapper around the aforementioned connector: [PySpark Cassandra](https://github.com/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra/). It is not feature complete with respect to the connector by Datastax, but a lot of stuff is there. Also, if performance is important, investigating the performance hit may be worth while.

Finally, Spark ships with a [python example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/cassandra_outputformat.py) of using the CqlInput/OutputFormat from hadoop mapreduce. Not a very developer friendly option in my opinion, but it's there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen your PySpark-Cassandra library, but it doesn't seem that it supports Cassandra 3, is this still the case?

Comment: @JimWright, pyspark-cassandra is built on https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector. A Cassandra 3 compatible version was released not so long ago (v1.5). Version 0.3.1 of pyspark-cassandra is built on that release and thus supports Cassandra 3.

Comment: Hi, on 11 OCT, you changed the README.md by adding this sentence: "PySpark Cassandra is no longer maintained. Development effort has moved away from Spark to pure Python environment.". What would be your update to your answer then?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and readint through your issue description: it doesn't appear that there is any Cassandra connector that you're using.  Spark doesn't come with Cassandra support out of the box as such the RDD and DStream data types don't have the `saveToCassandra` method.  You need to import an external Spark-Cassandra connector which extends the RDD and DStream types to support Cassandra integration.

This is why you're getting the error:  Python can't find any function `saveToCassandra` on the DStream type because none currently exists.

You'll need to get the DataStax connector or some other connector to extend the DStream type with `saveToCassandra`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am using the connector by datastax: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector, which I have specified what I run spark-submit.
I am new to Python, how do I know what I should import?

Comment: @JimWright how do you have Spark & PySpark setup?  Are you using DataStax Enterprise?  Also, are you using the pyspark shell or how are you trying to execute your code?

Comment: I am using the community edition, and am running on the command line through spark-submit: spark-submit --jars /var/spark/lib/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.5.0-RC1-s_2.11 /var/spark/scripts/kafka_cassandra.py